# How to create front-end (editable) Wordpress user profile pages?

Tags: users, forms, dashboard, profiles

So I am using Gravity Forms to create registration and login forms. But after the user logs in, I want them to be able to see a custom front-end profile page instead of the default Wordpress user dashboard. This page has to be catered based on the role the user signed up for.

I want to refrain from using any plugins (other than Gravity Forms extensions) because this profile page has information that must be integrated with another plugin called AlexaCRM to work with Microsoft Dynamics. AlexaCRM works in the Wordpress editor and with Gravity Forms. I'm pretty sure another plugin will make it not work altogether or complicate things.

How can I accomplish this from scratch or with a Gravity Forms add-on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using BuddyPress user profiles feature, you don't need to enable all BuddyPress features.

Gravity Forms can be used to create profile-like fields, but it is not really tied to real WordPress user profiles: https://www.gravityforms.com/creating-team-member-profiles/

Comment: Hi Stefano. We are using WPForo for the user forums on the site, so would installing BuddyPress conflict with that?

Comment: I guess I just want to create the front-end page so that it can also feed in Microsoft Dynamics data via the AlexaCRM plugin we purchased. That's why I want to refrain from using plugins that will likely complicate things. Or else I would have stuck with Ultimate Member which would make this a breeze.

Comment: i have found some instructions in a legacy Gravity Forms thread, they should work according to the messages.
Instructions: https://web.archive.org/web/20121124160319/http://blog.fublo.net/2011/12/edit-wordpress-user-profiles-gravity-forms/ù
Code: https://gist.github.com/mistergiri/1838012
The Wayback Machine page does not contain the code, that is available on Github (second link).

Answer (score -1):

Here are the following steps that can help you to achieve this.

- create child theme or plugin
- Create template file for that custom page ([Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/))
- Check login user user by using [get_curent_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)

- Now create form based on that information and update information based on that form
- Now last step create Wordpress page and select that template

Congratulation now you can edit user information from front end.